# UITextField inside UIScrollView freeze the app when click on the textfield to edit

Tags: swift, uitextfield, scrollview, freeze

swifters!

I am trying to add a many textfields inside a scrollview , and its working fine and the scrollview is scrolling just fine, but when I click on the any textfield to type any text he app freezing.

and I got this message on debug area **XPC connection interrupted**

can anyone help me!

here is my code for creating the scrollview and for the dynamic textfields

```
func setupScrollView() {

        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        container.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)

        scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        contentView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor , multiplier: 0.75).isActive = true
        contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
```

this is how I am adding the textfields :

```
let questionContainer = UIView()
        questionContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(questionContainer)

        if latestView == nil {

            questionContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        }

        else {

            questionContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: latestView!.bottomAnchor, constant: 32).isActive = true
        }

        questionContainer.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        questionContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        questionContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        questionContainer.backgroundColor = .red


        let question = UITextField()
        question.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        questionContainer.addSubview(question)
        question.text = "Test Test Test"
        question.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: questionContainer.topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        question.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: questionContainer.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
        question.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: questionContainer.bottomAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
        question.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: questionContainer.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
```

Comment: Is there any constraint failure in the console?

Comment: no, everything is working fine even if I add 100 textfields , but I cannot touch any view

Comment: is it possible to have a problem with container height? I can not see any height constraint settled. Have you checked with Debug View Hierarchy?

Comment: the container is inside the scroll view, thats why I didn't set the height constraint

Comment: all right, but scrollview contentSize must be set. And container height must be equal or bigger to contentsize of scrollview so that scrollview can be scrolled :)

Comment: I don't have any problem with scrolling as I told you everything is working fine till I touch any textfield

Comment: @erkutbas I updated the question, Please check the debug message, and thank you in advance :))

Comment: Im hitting the same issue beta 7